# Mysql Syntax error on creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL database inside a docker container.
The entrypoint executes a script creating the database and a script creating tables.

Everything works fine except for one table.

```
use db;

... creating other tables

CREATE TABLE mediametadata
(
id bigint not null  primary key,
title VARCHAR not NULL,
artist VARCHAR not NULL,
album VARCHAR,
releaseYear bigint,
mediaId bigint NOT NULL,
constraint fk__pk_metadata_objectid
        foreign key (id) references objectid (id),

constraint fk__metadata_media_id
        foreign key (mediaId) references media (id)
)
;
```

The error logged to console is

```
mysql_1  | ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 150: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not NULL,
mysql_1  | artist VARCHAR not NULL,
mysql_1  | album VARCHAR,
mysql_1  | releaseYear bigint,
mysql_1  | mediaId bi' at line 4
```

line 150 is the open bracket after `CREATE TABLE mediametadata`

- MySQL version: 8.0.3-rc-log
- Host OS: Debian jessie

I came to think `year` and `metadata` might be reserved keywords so I renamed the table and the `year` column but the error persists.

Comment: You need to give every VARCHAR a length. I'm pretty sure I've answered this question on Stack Overflow before.

Comment: @Bill Karwin is right. Just change VARCHAR to VARCHAR(length).

Comment: while your at it, dont create primary keys like this (unnamed) but name them just like you did with your foreign keys

Comment: thanks a lot ... too obvious did it for all the other tables forgot to set the varchar length here

Comment: @GuidoG, MySQL doesn't support naming primary keys. They are all called `PRIMARY`. Try it: `create table foo ( id int, constraint mypk primary key (id));` followed by `show create table foo` and you won't see "mypk" anywhere.

Comment: @BillKarwin weird that it allows the syntax when creating the table then...

Comment: @GuidoG, it's weird because MySQL has an "SQL layer" where most SQL parsing is done, but then other work is delegated to the storage engine layer. The constraint syntax is legal according to ANSI SQL, but the storage engine doesn't implement anything for it. Similarly, FOREIGN KEY declaration is a silent no-op when you use it with MyISAM, and CHECK constraints aren't implemented by any storage engine. In both cases, the syntax is accepted at the SQL layer, but the constraint is silently ignored. Bugs have been reported about this, but so far have not been addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answered by @Bill Karwin in first comment Varchar needs length  [Varchar(number)]